# I found a solution but can't post due to low reputation

Tags: discussion

I found that the Random Select by André Berg script mentioned in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65941/random-pattern-generation-in-illustrator?newreg=27fc75dddabc4c22b9fef2417b38c388) is no longer downloadable. So I created my own script to select random objects in Adobe Illustrator. You can find it here. https://ksoftlabs.com/select-random-objects-in-adobe-illustrator/.
But cann't share it in the original post as I don't have enough reputation. How can I share this with the community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting!

I just went ahead and updated my answer with a link to the script on a GitHub gist.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the answer with the script and hit the edit button. You can then edit it to include this information. Because of your rep it won't show up immediately but will enter a queue for approval.

Be sure to mention you wrote the script as part of your edit. StackExchange requires such things be disclosed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have found a solution, you can post it as an answer to your own question.